# Finding names to songs in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, musicbrainz

I have a collection of mp3, wma's etc that may or may not have the correct song information.

Is there a service or an API that I can use in .NET to find the correct song title / artist for each file?

Comment: An API based on the Id3 tags, file hashes, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of [Last.fm Fingerprint API](http://blog.last.fm/2010/07/09/fingerprint-api-and-app-updated). That should help you.

You could call their client app from within a C# app to automate the whole process of going through your media library and storing the returned results. You can even change your mp3 metadata on the fly.

More links to the stack:

[25 Music APIs](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2008/02/21/25-music-apis/)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Player (WMP) is pretty good at downloading album art and titles and such when you rip a CD, but it's far from perfect. If such an API existed in any location, let alone the highly public and well-used .NET platform, WMP would have a better track record.

Therefore it is logical to conclude that the answer is quite simply, "No."

I doubt such an API exists in any form, but if it might, it would likely be a web service.

Answer (score 0):

[freedb.org](http://www.freedb.org/en/download__miscellaneous.11.html) has what you need. I used it some years ago and it worked out great.

Download the file 'freedb howto v1.07' to get the details of how to implement this into your program.